# How to add class to the label if checkbox checked?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add class to the label if checkbox checked in WordPress?

```
<label class="ADD_CLASS_HERE">
    <input type="checkbox" name="moto" id="moto" value="yes" <?php checked( 'yes', $transport); ?> />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps better solved with some native PHP itself instead of relying on WordPress' helper functions. Where you want to output the class, just check the value and echo something based on the value you're expecting.

Assuming that `$transport` can be `'yes'` or `'no'`, I would probably use a [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for this

```
<label class="<?php echo ( filter_var($transport, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ) ? 'class-if-true' : 'class-if-false'; ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="moto" id="moto" value="yes" <?php checked( 'yes', $transport); ?> />
</label>
```

You can replace `( filter_var($transport, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) )` with whatever condition you want though, of course. `( $transport == 'yes' )` or `( $transport != 'no' )`, etc.

Comment: one more question)) How to check if checkbox is active (when just clicked on it), not checked? I also need this to add a border class to active checkbox.

Comment: You can use the [`:active` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) to control that with CSS. `input[type="checkbox"]:active { border: 2px solid #f00; }` for example

Comment: Yes, but I'm using framework and have a lot of different checkboxes))

Comment: Found solution with AlpineJS